# Unravel 1D list back to 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Basically, is there a way to transform a 1D list that has been "flattened" through the `numpy.ravel()` function back to it's original 3D form ? I know the dimensions, and one might ask why I just don't use the original 3D array in the first place, instead of converting it - but there reasons for that.

I just need to know if I can actually create the same 3D array from a 1D array that was created by using `numpy.ravel()` on the 3D array.

Basically the 3D array was created like this:

```
import numpy as np

nx = 50
ny = 40
nz = 150

x = np.linspace(1, 51, nx)
y = np.linspace(1, 41, ny)
z = np.linspace(1, 151, nz)

x_bc = x[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
y_bc = y[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
z_bc = z[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]

arr = x_bc + y_bc + z_bc
```

And nope, I can't just do this to get it back, since calculations has been done to it in the mean time, and then converted to a 1D array in the mean time as well. So the data in this array is not the same as the one I actually want to convert back.

Comment: You may be confusing lists and arrays. A 1D array is not a list. There are no lists whatsoever in your example. They are all arrays.

Comment: Play with something simpler, for example `arr = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)`.  That starts with a 1d (arange), makes it 3d, which can be raveled back to 1d, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `numpy.reshape` do what you want?

Comment: Oh dear, that I haven't even been looking at. Just thought there would be something like `unravel`, but for that I could only find `unravel_index`. Either way, it works :)

Comment: this isn't really an answer imo

Answer (score 5):

Just reshape it back to the original shape?

```
raveled = np.ravel(arr)
new_arr = raveled.reshape(*arr.shape)
```